# Google Cloud App Engine run custom app in privileged mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, gcsfuse

I have an app deployed on app engine in Google cloud. I need to be able to use gcsfuse to access shared bucket but you need to run the docker image in privileged mode to access resources.
If I deploy my docker image on compute engine I get the choice to start in privileged mode and gcsfuse works but not when deploying under app engine.
Any clues? Is it possible to mount a bucket inside an app engine app.

Comment: gcsfuse is kind of a hack, so I'll ask why do you need the bucket mounted? Will you have bash scripts manipulating files in the bucket, or is it just easier to interact with the filesystem than to use the GCS libraries from within the app?

Comment: Im experimenting getting magento 2 to run from app engine with cloudsql backend and a storage bucket to house the shared data aspects like catalog static media files. Just seems to make sense that i mount this onto the appropriate folder on the front end so they all serve from the same backend storage.